# Spring-MVC vs. raw Servlet: memory consumption, performance

Tags: performance, memory, servlets, spring-mvc

I was reading the question ["Raw Servlet vs. Spring MVC"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775522/raw-servlet-vs-spring-mvc) and was wondering if Spring MVC might slow down or blow up the memory consumption of your application compared with raw servlet?

Note: I originally asked it as a comment in the question mentioned above and was then kindly summoned to post it as a separate question.

Comment: It will certainly consume *more* memory because Spring MVC is a servlet + some architecture (compare to servlet alone). It will most likely not slow down the whole server, this framework is used in production by many, many companies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define "blow up". Define "slow down".

Of course memory usage will be higher, and of course performance will be lower.

How *much* higher, and lower compared to the additional functionality and flexibility Spring provides is the *real* question, and not knowing anything about the hypothetical app, it's impossible to say.

Building a testable, extensible, well-architected servlet-only app would involved re-implementing a lot of the functionality Spring provides. Which would you prefer to do--re-implement some (essentially) industry-standard code to the same degree it's been implemented and then write your app, or just write your app? And which would your *boss* prefer you do?

Comment: Thanks Dave Newton for your answer. You're right, it really depends on a lot of things. With your answer now I can think more about SpringMVC. And for your information: let's say it's a web application used by two person each day. The web application provides a lot of subapplication for persisting information, grids, scripting possibility, reporting and so forth. I'm wondering if SpringMVC is for that rather an overkill?

Comment: @nexus It still depends. Spring has a bunch of persistence abstractions built-in. The number of users isn't really the issue--it's ease of development, testing needs, etc.

Comment: So i guess it helps you developing better, proper applications and needs a bit more memory. It's rather - as you've said - an ease of development. Do you probably know how much memory SpringMVC per se needs after initalization?

Comment: @nexus I have no idea--it depends on how much you're having Spring do. Maybe do a development spike to provide yourself with an estimate, otherwise you may be over-thinking this at this point.

Comment: @nexus I can tell that Spring is really memory hungry and every redeploy takes more and more permgen (Meta) space memory that in times fire an Permgen(Meta)spaceOutOfMemoryException, but... if people think Spring pays the bill for them it's ok, but for me Spring is really huge, overcomplex, and, contrary to propaganda, heavyweight. Stick to the standard Java EE 6 / 7